# Comparar a quantidade de linhas de um list em uma ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, mvc, razor

Preciso saber a quantidade de linhas(na view) que envio do meu controller num tipo `list<>` para uma viewbag na view.
Com isso habilito ou não a opção de criar novas imagens.

Controller:

```
    ViewBag.Imagens =             _supplierAdvertImageRepository.GetSupplierAdvertImage(obj.SupplierAdvertID,
                obj.SupplierID);
```

View

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.Imagens > 5)
    {
        <div id="div_inseret">
            @Html.ActionLink(
                "Inserir Imagem ", 
                "CreateAdvertImage",
                "SupplierAdvert", 
                new {
                    supplierId = Model.SupplierID, 
                    SupplierAdvertID = Model.SupplierAdvertID}, 
                    new {
                        supplierId = Model.SupplierID, 
                        SupplierAdvertID = Model.SupplierAdvertID, 
                        @class = "btn btn-info"
                    }
            )
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <label for="Adress">Limite de Imagens Atingido
            <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
    }
```

porém não esta correto, alguém tem uma ideia melhor?

Comment: Sua pergunta está sem lógica, poderia [reformular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/462431/comparar-a-quantidade-de-linhas-de-um-list-em-uma-viewbag)?

Comment: Veja se agora tem lógica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
var lista = _supplierAdvertImageRepository
    .GetSupplierAdvertImage(obj.SupplierAdvertID, obj.SupplierID);
ViewBag.Imagens = lista;
ViewBag.Quantidade = lista.Count();
```

Na `View`

```
@if (int.TryParse(ViewBag.Quantidade.ToString(), out int c) && c > 5)
{
}
```

Comment: Virgílio, não tinha pensado nesta solução bem mais simples, mas resolveu obrigado!